# Seemingly random 404s on IIS hosted Blazor Wasm apps

Tags: .net, iis, blazor-webassembly

Hoping somebody out there has encountered this before:  I have several Blazor Wasm projects (some NET 5.0 created in VS 2019, some NET 6.0 in VS 2022) deployed on our production and test servers (IIS) and once deployed, they work... most of the time.  But every so often (a few times a day) some users will run into an issue where it either delivers a 404 or a Connection Timeout.

This outage (only for the user affected, other users can still access the site when this happens) can last just a few minutes or longer before it seems to magically resolve itself.  Sometimes, opening the site in an incognito window or different browser will work, sometimes not.  If we add an entry to the hosts file on the user's machine, that does appear to fix it, but this is not a solution we are happy with as we would have to update every machine in the company.  We are unable to reliably reproduce this and googling the issue has not been fruitful.  This is only happening for our blazor sites, we have a number of other .NET projects deployed on these servers that do not encounter this issue.

Anybody have any ideas?

Comment: While you didn't list all details above, I guess this is a browser side issue (other than server side) related to DNS. Then you need an expert who knows browser, client side DNS settings, and networking very well to assist. That's more likely to be a network administrator on sites like ServerFault, not a developer role here on Stack Overflow. He/she might need direct access to the machine that experiences the issue, so online discussion won't help much either.

Comment: It's impossible to analyze the problem based on these descriptions alone, you need to provide detailed error information, projects and environments that can reproduce the problem. But based on your description, these seem to be uncertain, it is difficult to reproduce your problem, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.